# How one can debug .CU file in MATLAB under linux platform

Tags: matlab, cuda

To do GPU parallel computing with MATLAB, one needs to write a .cu function, or kernel, which is called by MATLAB script. Is there any way I can step into the .cu file when the code is running? I am right now using a GEDIT to write a CUDA kernels. Could someone please give me a pointer on how to debug the .cu file step by step? I am not using that mex stuff for the CUDA. I am just developing .CU file and calling directly from MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you may be able to use Nsight EE or cuds-gdb to attach to Matlab process. Some gotcha's:

1. Device used for CUDA debugging should not be used for display (e.g. you need to have 2 GPUs in your system and connect display to GPU other then the one used for CUDA).
2. You should compile your CU file with debug information (pass -g -G to NVCC)

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene said, compile your `*.cu` with debug enabled

```
nvcc -g -G <insertName>.cu
```

Then pass `cuda-gdb` to MATLAB's debug option:

```
matlab -Dcuda-gdb
```

This will execute the debugger.  From the debugger prompt:

```
 (cuda-gdb) set cudamemcheck on
 (cuda-gdb) run -nodesktop -nojvm
```

Enabling `cudamemcheck` is optional, but very useful for identifying memory access violations.  The "run" command executes MATLAB, which I always do without the GUI (`-nodesktop`) and without the java virtual machine (`-nojvm`).  YMMV if you attempt this with the GUI.

At this point, you are within the MATLAB environment, and can proceed with running whatever (CUDA) programs are causing trouble.  You will need to learn the `cuda-gdb` commands.

Edit: per my experience, the `-nojvm` option must be used. Segfault otherwise.